# How to iterate textbox array in JS

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have text boxes in HTML like:

```
<table id="tbl">
<tr>
    <td><input type="text" name="t1[]"></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="t2[]"></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="t3[]"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><input type="text" name="t1[]"></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="t2[]"></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="t3[]"></td>
</tr> 
</table>
```

Now I want to fill the TextBoxes in first row with some value on `onchange` event of another textbox.
How should I do it?
The following answer by Rahul Fills all the textboxes with the same value but I want to only first 2 tds of first tr of given table with different values.

Please Help.

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to use a js library like jQuery. In jQuery you can do like this.

```
$(function(){
    $("yourtextboxselector").change(function(){
        $("#tbl1 tr:first input:text").each ( function(){
            $(this).val('new value');
        });
    });
});

<table id="tbl1">
<tr>
    <td><input type="text" name="t1[]" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="t2[]" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><input type="text" name="t1[]" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="t2[]" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><input type="text" name="t1[]" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="t2[]" /></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks dude for quick reply!

Can we do it in Mootools way?

Comment: Sorry, I am not familiar with mootools.